# Relationship between Poisson and Uniform distribution

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing

I'm reading this [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471696935) and on page 565 he solved an example about the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test:

[image]

I have two questions:

1. What Poisson distribution has to do with uniform distribution in this context?
2. Why is he including the difference $|F(x_i)-F_n(x_{i-1})|$ to find the [Kolmogorov-Smirnov statistic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test#Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_statistic) $T=\sup_{t} |F_n(t)-F(t)|$? we only need to calculate the supremum of the $|F(x_i)-F_n(x_{i})|$, no?

Comment: See [Theorem 5.2 here](http://www.stat.uchicago.edu/~yibi/teaching/stat317/2014/Lectures/Lecture10_6up.pdf). Also of possible interest [this page](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2000294/why-arrival-time-in-poisson-process-has-uniform-distribution-given-that-a-single) (even though it was closed for irrelevant reasons.)

Comment: @BruceET thank you very much, it solved my problem.